# Unclear ConcurrentModificationException on separate lists

Tags: java, concurrency

in a class I've those 2 methods:

```
public void notifyResult(List<Road> result) {
    ArrayList<RoadOverlay> tempRoads = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Road road:result){
    // Computes and stores the overlays
    // ...
        tempRoads.add(new RoadOverlay());
    }
    //switch field when update is done
    this.positions = tempRoads;
    }
}

private void drawRoadsVO(GL gl) {
    // keep a reference on the current instance of the field 
    // to avoid concurrent modification in notifyResult
    ArrayList<RoadOverlay> positionsCopy = this.positions;
    int vertexCount = 0;
    for (RoadOverlay road : positionsCopy) { //ConcurrentModificationException here
             // ...
        }
}
```

Both method run in separate threads. Inside rendering i make no change on the list, and to my understanding i work on separate lists so how could this produce CME?
I'm struggling on this one, and any clue would be welcome. As far as possible I try to avoid penalty of using synchronisation.

regards

*Edited a comment in the code*

Comment: `//work on a copy to avoid concurrent modification` You don't copy the list. You just have two different references pointing to the same instance.

Comment: i know it is not a shallow copy , but it was to be sure to keep the traversal on the same instance. You think that's useless?

Comment: The problem is that, as you said, your methods run on separate threads. As you're operating on the same instance, one thread might modify the list while you're reading from it in `drawRoadsVO`(that's why the CME is thrown). So either you'd need to make a deep copy before reading, or use a thread safe data structure.

Comment: Ok with that, but in the first method i create a new instance at each call, so  I still need to synchronize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually better to make full copy of a list

```
ArrayList<RoadOverlay> positionsCopy = new ArrayList<Integer>(this.positions);
```

As for `ConcurrentModificationException`, your code looks fine, may be you are modifying current `this.positions` in some other class methods?
Note that your `this.positions` variable should be declared as `volatile`.

Here is `next()` method of ArrayList iterator

```
public E next() {
    checkForComodification();
    int i = cursor;
    if (i >= size)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
    if (i >= elementData.length)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    cursor = i + 1;
    return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
}

final void checkForComodification() {
    if (modCount != expectedModCount)
       throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
}
```

`ConcurrentModificationException` could be thrown only in case then list's `elementData` is structurally modified

> Structural modifications are those that change the size of the list,
>   or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress
>   may yield incorrect results.

Comment: Yes i know i should prefer a synchronised  deep copy, but this code renders a road layer from OpenstreetMap with a lot of objects, and I'm hunting every performance hit. There's no other thread or method modifying the collection. I'm going to try to set it volatile, in case of jvm doing weird stuff behind the curtain

Comment: Hmm, right now I can't imagine how `volatile` could fix this. Where in `ArrayList.Itr` class CME is thrown? Could you post head of stack trace please

Comment: You're right, it changes nothing. here's a stack trace:                                         `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
 at org.mycompany.RoadProvider.drawRoadsVO[...]`

Comment: Volatile still is needed for visibility guarantees. `checkForComodification()` contains  `if (modCount != expectedModCount) throw new ConcurrentModificationException();` so structural modification happens somewhere. For debug you can make deep copy of `positionsCopy`  before the for loop then wrap loop with `try{} catch (ConcurrentModificationException ex) { //make another deep copy of `positionsCopy` and compare with the first deep copy or use java debugger and make a breakpoint here } `

Comment: Ok, I've found out where the problem was. Thanks to the details you gave about the modcount i noticed that modcount was changing during a rendering. it was a lame placement of a closure in notifiedResult, that induced the switch from local to field at each loop iteration. Yup, pretty lame. Anyway thanks for the helping hand ! regards

Answer (score 1):

the problem is inside drawRoadsVO method your var positionsCopy is not actually a copy, but a reference to the same object this.positions.

In order to make actual copy you should do

```
ArrayList<RoadOverlay> positionsCopy = new ArrayList(this.positions);
```